1st Esdras, Ezra-Nehemiah, 3rd Esdras, etc
According to the article 1 Esdras & The Canon Of Hippo, Carthage, & Trent, there are 2 and a half chapters from 1st Esdras (LXX end of 4th century, Council of Hippo/Carthage, 2nd Esdras = Ezra/Nehemiah of the Vulgata) supposedly missing in the Latin Vulgate (which only has Ezra and Nehemiah [= 2nd Esdras in the LXX).
Does anybody know anything about this? And what are the chapters supposedly missing? we have the LXX (Vaticanus, Sinaiticus, Alexandrinus) and Latin Vulgate.

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I also recommend going through the Help Center's sections on both asking and answering questions.
